# R barchart, not barplot, remove yaxis ticks

Tags: r, charts, axis

I am trying to remove the y-axis ticks from a barchart.

google immediately corrects barchart to barplot, and is not helpful at all.

yaxt="n" is not working with barchart...

Anyone have an idea how to remove the yaxis ticks in barcharts in R?

I need barchart because this is the only way I could find that works for me to group my data in the way I want it...

An MWE is here:

```
 library(lattice)

 molnames<-c("A","B","D","G","C","F")
 contactcounts<-c(1,2,3, 6,12,18,4,8,16,10,20,30,2,4,8,3,6,9)

 Acolumn1=factor(rep(molnames, each=3), levels=molnames )
 Acolumn2=rep(c("test1","test2","test3"), 6)
 Acolumn3=contactcounts
 colour<-c("orange", "blue","magenta")
 tiff(file="./testingABC.tiff", res=1000, width = 8, height = 8,units='in')
 trellis.par.set("grid.pars"=list(fontfamily="serif"))
 barchart(Acolumn3 ~ Acolumn1,ylab="y axis", yaxt="n", groups=Acolumn2,  auto.key = list(columns = 3),  par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=colour)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you're using a function from lattice package, not from base package and it has different parameters.
To accomplish what you want, you should set `scales` parameter (see `?barchart` documentation); there are two options giving a slighlty different result :

```
# option 1: we're saying that y ticks must be set at coordinate = NULL
barchart(Acolumn3 ~ Acolumn1,ylab="y axis", groups=Acolumn2,  auto.key = list(columns = 3),  
         scales=list(y=list(at=NULL)),
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=colour)))
```

[image]

```
# option 2: we're saying not to draw y axis
barchart(Acolumn3 ~ Acolumn1,ylab="y axis", groups=Acolumn2,  auto.key = list(columns = 3),  
         scales=list(y=list(draw=FALSE)),
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=colour)))
```

[image]

---

Here's an example how to do a barplot using base R:

```
# Acolumn1,Acolumn2,Acolumn3 have been created in your example
DF <- data.frame(Acolumn1,Acolumn2,Acolumn3)

###### build matrix to be passed to barplot using R base
reshaped <- reshape(DF, idvar="Acolumn1",timevar="Acolumn2", direction = "wide",sep='_')
names(reshaped) <- gsub('Acolumn3_','',names(reshaped))
reshapedMx <- as.matrix(reshaped[,-1])
rownames(reshapedMx) <- reshaped[,1]
reshapedMx <- t(reshapedMx)

###### build matrix to be passed to barplot using reshape2 package (less code)
# library(reshape2)
# reshapedMx <- acast(DF, Acolumn1 ~ Acolumn2, value.var='Acolumn3')
# reshapedMx <- t(reshapedMx)

colors <- rainbow(nrow(reshapedMx))
barplot(reshapedMx,beside = TRUE,col=colors,ylim=c(0,max(reshapedMx)*1.2), yaxt='n')
legend('top',fill=colors,legend=rownames(reshapedMx), horiz=TRUE)
# call box() if you want to add a box around the plot
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that works fine. Any idea how to only hide the ticks for the secondary y axis?

Comment: I don't see any seconday y axis here, please provide an example... BTW any reason to use lattice instead of base plot ?

Comment: this was the only method I could find that actually did what I wanted and worked (and that I understood...)
When I plot the MWE, I get a secondary y axis on the left, with ticks...
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and R 3.2.2

Comment: I don't know, as you can see it does not appear on my machine... anyway I've added an example using base barplot, if you want to try it...

Comment: I like the version with barplot very much!
Is barchart discontinued or not recommended to work with?

Comment: @gugy: no, I think lattice is a pretty good package and actively maintained; I just don't know it very well so I wanted to show an alternative using base barplot (which is easier to customize since there are a lot of examples on the internet) ;)